# Cannot view data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have covered many tutorials and articles but can not find exactly what I need to assist me in resolving my issue.

My issue is that my compiled dll does not return rows of data from my SQL database file to the `DataGridView`.

I have created this project as a windows application for testing and it works fine. However, when I change the output to a class library it runs but does not return any data to the `DataGridView`. The header is there, because it is declared, but I have a feeling the compiled dll can not establish a connection to the database.

I have experience with C# and ASP but not in creating dll's.

To also clarify further, I can use the `dataset` or the `bindingsource` before I compile and view all the records using the Preview Data option. Is there a specific way you have to setup the database connection when creating a class library in my situation?

SQLDatabase.mdf Connection String:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SQLDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

Designer Generated Code: this.itemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.abDataSet.Items);

Please let me know if you would like me to post the Form.Designer.cs which was Designer Generated Code as well. Again, everything works fine as a Windows Application but as a Class Library the rows of data are never displayed in the DataGridView.

```
namespace AHPriceChecker4Free
{
    public class AHPriceChecker : Core
    {
        private Thread formThread;

        public void PluginStop()
        {
            Log("closed");
        }

        private AHCheckerForm ahForm;
        public bool formIsOpen;

        public void PluginRun()
        {
            formThread = new Thread(RunForm);
            formThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            formThread.Start();
            formIsOpen = true;
            while (formIsOpen)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void RunForm()
        {
            ahForm = new AHCheckerForm(this, me);
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ahForm);
        }
    }
}
```

Form.cs

```
namespace AHPriceChecker4Free
{
    partial class AHCheckerForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(AHCheckerForm));
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.tsmMain = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.tsmLoad = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.tsmSave = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.txtItemName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.btnSearch = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.ofdOpen = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            this.sfdSave = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
            this.btnMassSearch = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.itemPriceHistory = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.itemAveragePrice = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.itemLastPrice = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.itemName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.dgvAuctionTable = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
            this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.rtbSave = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.tabPage3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.label8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.tabPage4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.itemNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.goldDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.silverDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.copperDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.perQtyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.abchristDataSet = new AHPriceChecker4Free.abchristDataSet();
            this.itemsTableAdapter = new AHPriceChecker4Free.abchristDataSetTableAdapters.ItemsTableAdapter();
            this.itemsBindingSource1 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dgvAuctionTable)).BeginInit();
            this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabPage2.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabPage3.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabPage4.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.abchristDataSet)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.itemsBindingSource1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.tsmMain});
            this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(7, 2, 0, 2);
            this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(819, 24);
            this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.ItemClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(this.menuStrip1_ItemClicked);
            // 
            // tsmMain
            // 
            this.tsmMain.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.tsmLoad,
            this.tsmSave});
            this.tsmMain.Name = "tsmMain";
            this.tsmMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 20);
            this.tsmMain.Text = "&Main";
            // 
            // tsmLoad
            // 
            this.tsmLoad.Name = "tsmLoad";
            this.tsmLoad.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(123, 22);
            this.tsmLoad.Text = "&Load data";
            this.tsmLoad.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tsmLoad_Click);
            // 
            // tsmSave
            // 
            this.tsmSave.Name = "tsmSave";
            this.tsmSave.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(123, 22);
            this.tsmSave.Text = "&Save data";
            this.tsmSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.transferDataToSave);
            // 
            // txtItemName
            // 
            this.txtItemName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
            this.txtItemName.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.txtItemName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 353);
            this.txtItemName.Name = "txtItemName";
            this.txtItemName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(203, 20);
            this.txtItemName.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // btnSearch
            // 
            this.btnSearch.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
            this.btnSearch.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnSearch.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(217, 351);
            this.btnSearch.Name = "btnSearch";
            this.btnSearch.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(87, 25);
            this.btnSearch.TabIndex = 5;
            this.btnSearch.Text = "Search";
            this.btnSearch.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnSearch.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSearch_Click);
            // 
            // ofdOpen
            // 
            this.ofdOpen.FileName = "openFileDialog1";
            // 
            // sfdSave
            // 
            this.sfdSave.FileOk += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.sfdSave_FileOk);
            // 
            // btnMassSearch
            // 
            this.btnMassSearch.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
            this.btnMassSearch.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnMassSearch.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(310, 351);
            this.btnMassSearch.Name = "btnMassSearch";
            this.btnMassSearch.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 25);
            this.btnMassSearch.TabIndex = 8;
            this.btnMassSearch.Text = "Mass search";
            this.btnMassSearch.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnMassSearch.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnMassSearch_Click);
            // 
            // itemPriceHistory
            // 
            this.itemPriceHistory.HeaderText = "Price History";
            this.itemPriceHistory.Name = "itemPriceHistory";
            this.itemPriceHistory.ReadOnly = true;
            this.itemPriceHistory.Width = 350;
            // 
            // itemAveragePrice
            // 
            this.itemAveragePrice.HeaderText = "Average price";
            this.itemAveragePrice.Name = "itemAveragePrice";
            this.itemAveragePrice.ReadOnly = true;
            this.itemAveragePrice.Width = 110;
            // 
            // itemLastPrice
            // 
            this.itemLastPrice.HeaderText = "Last price";
            this.itemLastPrice.Name = "itemLastPrice";
            // 
            // itemName
            // 
            this.itemName.Frozen = true;
            this.itemName.HeaderText = "Name";
            this.itemName.Name = "itemName";
            this.itemName.ReadOnly = true;
            this.itemName.Width = 200;
            // 
            // dgvAuctionTable
            // 
            this.dgvAuctionTable.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cornsilk;
            this.dgvAuctionTable.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dgvAuctionTable.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.itemName,
            this.itemLastPrice,
            this.itemAveragePrice,
            this.itemPriceHistory});
            this.dgvAuctionTable.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.dgvAuctionTable.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.dgvAuctionTable.Name = "dgvAuctionTable";
            this.dgvAuctionTable.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.dgvAuctionTable.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(805, 342);
            this.dgvAuctionTable.TabIndex = 1;
            this.dgvAuctionTable.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dgvAuctionTable_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
            //



 **// *** REMOVED ALL TABS BUT THE ONE I AM HAVING AN ISSUE WITH TO REDUCE SIZE. THIS FORM BODY IS LIMITED TO 30000 CHARACTERS WHEN POSTING *** //
            //** 



            // tabPage4
            // 
            this.tabPage4.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.tabPage4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 23);
            this.tabPage4.Name = "tabPage4";
            this.tabPage4.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(811, 381);
            this.tabPage4.TabIndex = 3;
            this.tabPage4.Text = "Database";
            this.tabPage4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.itemNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.goldDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.silverDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.copperDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.perQtyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn});
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.itemsBindingSource1;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(66, 69);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(669, 194);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Id";
            this.idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Id";
            this.idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
            // 
            // itemNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.itemNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ItemName";
            this.itemNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "ItemName";
            this.itemNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "itemNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.itemNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
            // 
            // goldDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.goldDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Gold";
            this.goldDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Gold";
            this.goldDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "goldDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.goldDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
            // 
            // silverDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.silverDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Silver";
            this.silverDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Silver";
            this.silverDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "silverDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.silverDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
            // 
            // copperDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.copperDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Copper";
            this.copperDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Copper";
            this.copperDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "copperDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.copperDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
            // 
            // perQtyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.perQtyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "PerQty";
            this.perQtyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "PerQty";
            this.perQtyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "perQtyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.perQtyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
            // 
            // abchristDataSet
            // 
            this.abchristDataSet.DataSetName = "abchristDataSet";
            this.abchristDataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
            // 
            // itemsTableAdapter
            // 
            this.itemsTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
            // 
            // itemsBindingSource1
            // 
            this.itemsBindingSource1.DataMember = "Items";
            this.itemsBindingSource1.DataSource = this.abchristDataSet;
            // 
            // AHCheckerForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 14F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cornsilk;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(819, 432);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
            this.Name = "AHCheckerForm";
            this.Text = "AHPriceChecker4Free - By Cobras.Club";
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.AHCheckerForm_FormClosed);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.AHCheckerForm_Load);
            this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dgvAuctionTable)).EndInit();
            this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tabPage1.PerformLayout();
            this.tabPage2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tabPage2.PerformLayout();
            this.tabPage3.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tabPage3.PerformLayout();
            this.tabPage4.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.abchristDataSet)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.itemsBindingSource1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem tsmMain;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem tsmLoad;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtItemName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSearch;
        private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofdOpen;
        private System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog sfdSave;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnMassSearch;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem tsmSave;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn itemPriceHistory;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn itemAveragePrice;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn itemLastPrice;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn itemName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dgvAuctionTable;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtbSave;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label8;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label7;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private abchristDataSet abchristDataSet;
        private abchristDataSetTableAdapters.ItemsTableAdapter itemsTableAdapter;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn itemNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn goldDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn silverDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn copperDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn perQtyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource itemsBindingSource1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide more context, post some code. Are you getting any exceptions? After you convert to class library, where are you referencing it? Did you try debugging the code to see what is happening?

Comment: .dll is same code library like .exe but without execution entry - `Main()` method. So type of the project isn't your problem. Maybe some initialization code was in the `Main` method and it will not be executed if project type was changed to the "Class library"

Comment: I updated with some code for review. I could only add so much because of this sites limitation of characters. I do not get any exceptions. I was thinking about building a separate console application just for the 1 tab I have the issue with concerning the datagridview so I can debug the datagridview and the passing of rows to it.

Comment: A class library (dll) requires a host application to execute. Suggest that you move your class library to a class library project and set a project reference from your windows forms project. Additionally you will need to set your connection string from the app.config in your windows project.

Comment: @Gregg I will try that. I was wondering how the connection string in the app.config gets used after compilation? Mine was auto generated as    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SQLDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"        and I was thinking my problem is here after I compiled it as a dll.

Comment: You have to add code in your class library that will let you set the connection string. The place to set the connection string is in the constructor of your class library. You can manually add the connection string like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add code in your class library that will let you set the connection string. The place to set the connection string is in the constructor of your class library. You can manually add the connection string like this in the app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;  
      AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
      Trusted_Connection=Yes;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then access the configuration string like this:

```
var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to go back to the basics and break it down. The issue turns out to be more of a .net security issue. I wrote all the code from scratch instead of having any of it generated and stayed away as much as possible from anything other than raw C# code. This project is now working. The only thing I have to work out now are the cosmetic graphical glitches that come up when it opens. It captures the background screen to the datagridview when it opens.